# When you first start a system boot, are you in kernel mode or user mode? Why?

Tags: operating-systems

I'm confused as to what mode computers boot in. My thought process was that since kernel mode is effectively the base layer of protection for the computer, it would boot in kernel mode and then load user mode. User mode is also effectively a subset of kernel mode? So you would have to load kernel mode before switching into user mode, right?

Comment: Kernel mode.Go through http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/linux-boot-process/ this will clear you the booting process.

Comment: How is this a computer *science* question? Community votes, please: offtopic?

Comment: @Raphael Dijkstra notwithstanding, computer architecture is a branch of computer science.

Comment: @Gilles To me, this seems to be more of a question about PCs than about operating systems concepts. If it can be read and answered as the latter, I'm okay.

Comment: I think the answer depends on when "booting" ends. Especially in microkernel OSes, I would say much of the "booting" process is done in both user mode (mostly) and kernel mode. At the very beginning of the bootstrap, it has to be either in kernel mode, or in user mode with a very loose memory access configuration (albeit the latter looks as a mostly theoretical possibility than a good practice).